# Increment filename

Tags: c#, optimization

I want to create algorithm, to generate name for new file which I want to add to main directory.
All files in this directory must has unique name and start with "myFile"

What do you think about this algorithm ? Can I optimize it ?

```
string startFileName="myFile.jpg";
string startDirectory="c:\MyPhotosWithSubFoldersAndWithFilesInMainDirectory";

bool fileWithThisNameExists = false;
string tempName = null;
do
{

    tempName = startFileName +"_"+ counter++ + Path.GetExtension(startFileName);
    foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(startDirectory)
    {
        if (Path.GetFileName(tempName) == Path.GetFileName(file))
        {
            fileWithThisNameExists = true;
        }
    }

    if (fileWithThisNameExists) continue;
    foreach (var directory in Directory.GetDirectories(startDirectory))
    {
        foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(directory))
        {
            if (Path.GetFileName(tempName) == Path.GetFileName(file))
            {
                fileWithThisNameExists = true;
            }
        }
    }
} while (fileWithThisNameExists);
```

Comment: For the algorithm I would go with GUID's like Kangkan suggested. But looking at your code it looks like you are trying to do something windows can do easily for you. 

On Windows XP and later versions of Windows, it is possible to rename multiple files at once via Explorer by selecting the files to rename, then pressing the F2 key.

Just to give a new name and press Enter. All files will be renamed and then followed by an incremented number in brackets.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not worried about the rest of the file name (except the starting as "myFile", then you can simply create a GUID and concat it to the worg "myFile". This is the simplest way. The other way might be taking the syste ticks and add it as a string to the word "myFile".

Answer (score 2):

If you construct your filenames so that they sort alphabetically

```
base000001
base000002
...
base000997
```

Then you can get a directory listing and just go to the end of the list to find the last file.

Be careful though: what happens if two instances of your program are running at the same time? There's a little window of opportunity between the test for the file existing and its creation.